# Do List.Exist using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, list, exists

I want to check if any of the items in a list has a field set to `true`

at the moment I do this:

```
bool isPaid = visit.Referrals.Exists(delegate(AReferral r)
                                     {
                                         return r.IsPaidVisit;
                                     });
```

How can I do this using `Linq` might be trivial to some but can't figure if now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
using System.Linq;

...

bool isPaid = visit.Referrals.Any(r => r.IsPaidVisit);
```

but why use the Linq library when you can do the following:

```
bool isPaid = visit.Referrals.Exists(r => r.IsPaidVisit);
```

Comment: @odyodyodys You have to use lambda expressions or delegates. May I ask why you won't use lambdas?

Comment: At first I was trying to do it using `from select` statement and I was wondering if it also can be done this way.

Comment: @odyodyodys You can't. At least not without redefining `where` and `select` <- very VERY bad solution.